# Why my validation accuracy is much higher than train accuracy, but the test accuracy is only 0.5?

Tags: keras, neural-network

I am doing some image classification using inception_v3 model in keras, however, my train accuracy is lower than validation during the whole training process. And my validation accuracy is above 0.95 from the first epoch. I also find that train loss is much higher than validation loss. In the end, the test accuracy is 0.5, which is pretty bad.

At first, my optimizer is Adam with learning rate equals to 0.00001, the result is bad. Then I change it to SGD with learning rate of 0.00001, which doesn't make any change to the bad result. I also tried to increase the learning rate to 0.1, but the test accuracy is still around 0.5

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import model_from_json
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import copy
import pydotplus


train_path = 'data/train'
valid_path = 'data/validation'
test_path = 'data/test'
top_model_weights_path = 'model_weigh.h5'

# number of epochs to train top model
epochs = 100
# batch size used by flow_from_directory and predict_generator
batch_size = 2

img_width, img_height = 299, 299
fc_size = 1024
nb_iv3_layers_to_freeze = 172

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                                   rotation_range=30,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)
# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                                   rotation_range=30,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)


train_batches = 
     train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                       target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                       classes=None,
                                       class_mode='categorical',
                                       batch_size=batch_size,
                                       shuffle=True)
valid_batches = 
     valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                       target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                       classes=None,
                                       class_mode='categorical',
                                       batch_size=batch_size,
                                       shuffle=True)
test_batches = 
    ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                             target_size=(img_width, 
                                                          img_height),
                                             classes=None,
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             shuffle=False)

nb_train_samples = len(train_batches.filenames)  
# get the size of the training set
nb_classes_train = len(train_batches.class_indices)  
# get the number of classes
predict_size_train = int(math.ceil(nb_train_samples / batch_size))

nb_valid_samples = len(valid_batches.filenames)
nb_classes_valid = len(valid_batches.class_indices)
predict_size_validation = int(math.ceil(nb_valid_samples / batch_size))

nb_test_samples = len(test_batches.filenames)
nb_classes_test = len(test_batches.class_indices)
predict_size_test = int(math.ceil(nb_test_samples / batch_size))


def add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes):
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(fc_size, activation='relu')(x)
    pred = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=pred)
    return model


# freeze base_model layer in order to get the bottleneck feature
def setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model):
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00001),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


base_model = keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes_train)
setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model)

model.summary()

train_labels = train_batches.classes
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=nb_classes_train)

validation_labels = valid_batches.classes
validation_labels = to_categorical(validation_labels, num_classes=nb_classes_train)

history = model.fit_generator(train_batches,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
                              validation_data=valid_batches,
                              validation_steps=nb_valid_samples // batch_size,
                              class_weight='auto')

# save model to json
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize model to HDF5
model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
print("Saved model to disk")

# model visualization
plot_model(model,
           show_shapes=True,
           show_layer_names=True,
           to_file='model.png')

(eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate_generator(
    valid_batches,
    steps=nb_valid_samples // batch_size,
    verbose=1)
print("[INFO] evaluate accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(eval_accuracy * 100))
print("[INFO] evaluate loss: {}".format(eval_loss))

test_batches.reset()
predictions = model.predict_generator(test_batches,
                                      steps=nb_test_samples / batch_size,
                                      verbose=0)
# print(predictions)

predicted_class_indices = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
# print(predicted_class_indices)

labels = train_batches.class_indices
labels = dict((v, k) for k, v in labels.items())
final_predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
# print(final_predictions)

# save as csv file
filenames = test_batches.filenames
results = pd.DataFrame({"Filename": filenames,
                        "Predictions": final_predictions})
results.to_csv("results.csv", index=False)

# evaluation test result
(test_loss, test_accuracy) = model.evaluate_generator(
    test_batches,
    steps=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    verbose=1)
print("[INFO] test accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(test_accuracy * 100))
print("[INFO] test loss: {}".format(test_loss))
```

Here is a brief summary of training process:

```
Epoch 1/100
2000/2000 [==============================] - 146s 73ms/step - loss: 0.4941 - acc: 0.7465 - val_loss: 0.1612 - val_acc: 0.9770
Epoch 2/100
2000/2000 [==============================] - 140s 70ms/step - loss: 0.4505 - acc: 0.7725 - val_loss: 0.1394 - val_acc: 0.9765
Epoch 3/100
2000/2000 [==============================] - 139s 70ms/step - loss: 0.4505 - acc: 0.7605 - val_loss: 0.1643 - val_acc: 0.9560
......
Epoch 98/100
2000/2000 [==============================] - 141s 71ms/step - loss: 0.1348 - acc: 0.9467 - val_loss: 0.0639 - val_acc: 0.9820
Epoch 99/100
2000/2000 [==============================] - 140s 70ms/step - loss: 0.1495 - acc: 0.9365 - val_loss: 0.0780 - val_acc: 0.9770
Epoch 100/100
2000/2000 [==============================] - 138s 69ms/step - loss: 0.1401 - acc: 0.9458 - val_loss: 0.0471 - val_acc: 0.9890
```

Here is the result that I get:

```
[INFO] evaluate accuracy: 98.55%
[INFO] evaluate loss: 0.05201659869024259
2000/2000 [==============================] - 47s 23ms/step
[INFO] test accuracy: 51.70%
[INFO] test loss: 7.737395915810134
```

I wish someone can help me deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. I forget to do image preprocessing to my test data. After I add this, everything works really fine.
I change this:

```py
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                             target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                             classes=None,
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             shuffle=False)
```

to this:

```py
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

test_batches = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                classes=None,
                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                shuffle=False)
```

And the test accuracy is 0.98, test loss is 0.06.

Answer (score 0):

As the code is now, you're not freezing the layers of the model for transfer learning. In the `setup_to_transfer_learn` you're freezing the layer in `base_model`, and then compiling the new model (containing layers from the base model), but not actually freezing on the new model. Just change `setup_to_transfer_learn`:

```
def setup_to_transfer_learn(model):
    for layer in model.layers[:-3]:    # since you added three new layers (which should not freeze)
        layer.trainable = False
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then call the function like this:

```
model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes_train)
setup_to_transfer_learn(model)
```

You should see a large difference in the number of trainable parameters when calling `model.summary()`

Comment: Thanks, the trainable params are fewer now. But my test accuracy is still 0.5, and training loss and accuracy are still a lot lower than validation loss and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is that when you use preprocessing the model may actually start learning those techniques. One way to check if your model is learning good features is using Grad-CAM